# cap staging deploy: bash: bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rbenv

I am running my Rails 5 project on CentOS 7 with `rbenv`. When i run `cap staging deploy` i got the error:

```
cd /srv/www/stagings/testproject/current; bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging stderr: bash: bundle: command not found

** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:

  INFO [f7a6296f] Finished in 0.256 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

I can run `bundle install` in deploy directory `/srv/www/stagings/testproject/current`
without any problem.

**.bash_profile**

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
export PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

**ruby, gem, bundler** versions:

```
which ruby
~/.rbenv/shims/ruby
which bundle
~/.rbenv/shims/bundle' 
which gem
~/.rbenv/shims/gem
```

I tried

```
 gem uninstall bundler
 gem install bundler`
```

doesn't work.
Any help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You should use capistrano/rbenv. Capistrano does not start an interactive shell via ssh. So your `.bash_profile` will not be loaded.